# Why SMPP bind Transmitter return error 0x34 (ESME_RINVDLNAME)

Tags: php, smpp

It`s my first time to write PHP code that sends SMS through
SMPP [Short Message peer to Peer] protocol by onlinecity php-smpp library from gethub URL: **https://github.com/onlinecity/php-smpp**,
I used the code below which sending SMS, but its only response an error 
**The return value is error 0x34 (ESME_RINVDLNAME) Invalid Distribution List Name.**
So please help me to resolve this error

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['SMPP_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__); // assumes this file is in the root
require_once $GLOBALS['SMPP_ROOT'].'/protocol/smppclient.class.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['SMPP_ROOT'].'/protocol/gsmencoder.class.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['SMPP_ROOT'].'/transport/tsocket.class.php';

// Simple debug callback
function printDebug($str) {
    //echo date('Ymd H:i:s ').$str."\r\n";
}

try {
    // Construct transport and client, customize settings
    $transport = new TSocket('192.168.111.1',5016,false,'printDebug'); // hostname/ip (ie. localhost) and port (ie. 2775)
    //print_r($transport);
    $transport->setRecvTimeout(10000);
    $transport->setSendTimeout(10000);
    $smpp = new SmppClient($transport,'printDebug');
    print_r($smpp);
    // Activate debug of server interaction
    $smpp->debug = true;        // binary hex-output
    $transport->setDebug(true); // also get TSocket debug
    
    // Open the connection
    $transport->open();
    
    $smpp->bindTransmitter("username","password");
    

    // Prepare message
    $message = 'Hello world';
    $encodedMessage = GsmEncoder::utf8_to_gsm0338($message);
    $from = new SmppAddress(GsmEncoder::utf8_to_gsm0338('5672'),SMPP::TON_ALPHANUMERIC);
    $to = new SmppAddress('967777841622',SMPP::TON_INTERNATIONAL,SMPP::NPI_E164);
    
    // Send

    $smpp->sendSMS($from,$to,$encodedMessage);
    //print_r($smpp);
    // Close connection
//  print_r($smpp);
    $smpp->close();
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Try to unbind
    try {
        $smpp->close();
    } catch (Exception $ue) {
        // if that fails just close the transport
        printDebug("Failed to unbind; '".$ue->getMessage()."' closing transport");
        if ($transport->isOpen()) $transport->close();
    }
    
    // Rethrow exception, now we are unbound or transport is closed
    throw $e; 
}
```

Comment: hello. I need help for this problem 

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow. As I don't have a direct answer I'll keep to the comments, however I would like to make a few observations. 1. This looks like you are using the php-smpp project from onlinecity on GitHub, please say so in the question. 2.That library was last updated 6 years ago and is designed for PHP 5x (very old), consider a newer code source as you may encounter incompatibilities, 3. Look at your code again, I noticed username and password have not been filled in. 4. Show what you've done to fix the issue, people will more likely help if you do. Good luck!

Comment: First of all, thank you  Kodaloid for remembering me to add the reference to the library, second thing for the credential of username and password, I can`t share it because of its real connection info to SMSC. I need help with interpreting this error and how to solve the issue .

Comment: I found this issue belong into SMPP interface version , which php-smpp project from onlinecity on GitHub using v3.4 [0x34] , however, this version is blocked from SMSC. when I changed the interface version from 3.4 [0x34] int 0.3 [0x03] code working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue belong into SMPP interface version , which  **php-smpp project from onlinecity** on GitHub using v3.4 [0x34] , however, this version is blocked from SMSC.
when I changed the interface version from 3.4 [0x34] into 0.3 [0x03]
code working fine.

Comment: That's good to hear! If this was the solution to your question, please mark it as the correct answer. Koda